# How to get input label instead of value from HTML input?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have angular material form fields with mat-select all over my calculator, they look like such:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mr-5">
  <mat-label>{{'INP.pipeTypeForm'|translate}}</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="pipeTypeMeasureControl">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let pipeType of pipeTypeMeasureList" [value]="pipeType.pipeType">
      {{pipeType.pipeName|translate}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

At some point in code I need to show user the option he chose, but not the value (as it's not in the best form to show) but as a select option he chose. pipeTypeMeasureList here is basically an array of objects that looks like this:

```
 pipeTypeMeasureList: { pipeType: string, pipeName: string }[] = [
    {pipeType: 'PVC', pipeName: __('UNITS.pvc')},
    {pipeType: 'HDPE', pipeName: __('UNITS.hdpe')}
  ]
```

So instead of writing in a string array the value of chosen option (which will be 'PVC' or 'HDPE') I want to write in the pipeName. What is the better approach from it, because the only ones I think about looks very unoptimized (Like creating a very stupid 'if' construction)

Answer (score 0):

You can just give the full object as the value of your option :

```html
 [value]="pipeType"
```

This way you get the full object value and can display any key you want in it.